# Error IronPython+C# 3.5

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm using the implementation of ironpython 2.6.2 in my application c# 3.5, but I'm getting the following error: "The method or operation is not implemented."

Added references to the DLR and IronPython assemblies (all found in the IronPython install directory, which is “C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.6” on my machine):

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
```

follows the code of my application:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();        
//parameter file path       
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(pathFilePy);        
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
ObjectOperations op = engine.Operations;
source.Execute(scope); // class object
object classObject = scope.GetVariable("calc"); // get class object        
object instance = op.Invoke(classObject); // create instance
object method = op.GetMember(instance, "calc01"); // get method        
var result = op.Invoke(method, 10, 20,30); // call method and get result
```

the code file .py

```
class calc(object):
    def calc01(self,var1,var2,var3):
        bla = ((var1+var2+var3)/3)
        return bla
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
var result = op.Invoke(method, 10, 20,30); // call method and get result
```

Comment: where do you get the error?  on which line?

Comment: var result = op.Invoke(method, 10, 20,30); // call method and get result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should call it with 4 arguments instead of 3 like this:

```
>>> class calc(object):
...     def calc01(self,var1,var2,var3):
...         bla = ((var1+var2+var3)/3)
...         return bla
...
>>> calc1 = calc()
>>> calc.calc01(calc1,10,20,30)
20
>>>
```

Comment: sorry, but I could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

as was pointed out  in the other answer it looks like your method needs 4 parameters and is only being invoked with 3 from the c# code.  the question I would ask (not being a python expert) is why your python method has the parameter `self` at all?  I would have thought you need to do 1 of 2 things, both of which will probably solve your problem

1 Redfine your python method not to contain self:

```
class calc(object):
def calc01(var1,var2,var3):
    bla = ((var1+var2+var3)/3)
    return bla
```

2 Invoke the python method using 4 arguments:

```
...
object classObject = scope.GetVariable("calc"); // get class object        
object instance = op.Invoke(classObject); // create instance
object method = op.GetMember(instance, "calc01"); // get method        
var result = op.Invoke(method, instance, 10, 20,30); // call method and get result
...
```

Comment: I followed your tip, but did not solve my problem, the same error occurred.
maybe I could change my code, but do not know how (I'm not an expert in python).
I need to invoke the method of a python file and send the parameters, I do not need a class.

Comment: just out of interest, did you do both at the same time, or did you try just making one change, then reverting and making the other.  I think you only need to make one of the two changes above.